# near unexpected error in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, nlp

I was going through NLP with python and I encountered 2 functions from matplot lib. , .plot and .dispersion_plot respectively.I encountered following error while running it..

```
:~$ fdist1.plot( 50 , cumulative = True)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `50'
~$ text4.dispersion_plot(["citizens","democraacy","freedom","duties","America"])
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `["citizens","democraacy","freedom","duties","America"]'
```

I have installsed matplotlib by pip and running ubuntu 14.04LTS ,I am new to python so can someone give me quick reference for NLP in python.

Comment: You are typing your code in at the bash (terminal) prompt, not the Python interpreter prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you start the python interpreter:

```
→ python < --------- bash prompt
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul  3 2014, 16:35:39)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> < -------- python interpreter
```